# Enabling CORS for a Angular - Flask Web Application

Tags: angular, flask

I've been trying to integrate my angular web application into my Flask API and I can't find anything to help me get over the CORS error when sending my POST methods. I've been able to access my MySQL database through the Flask API by using Postman, and have even been able to use the GET endpoint of the API through my angular app, but it starts to error whenever I use the POST method through angular. From what I've read, this a problem with my API not recognizing the origin of my webservice because they are running on different ports, but I'm not too sure.

The error says "XMLHttpRequest at [API] from origin [Webservice] has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp7iG.png)

My Flask API endpoints look like this: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWfQT.png)

My webservice GET and POST requests look like this: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4E4b.png)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used Flask, but this might help
https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest.
In the screenshot you seem to be importing it but it's not being used.

Comment: After looking back over my code and seeing if this may have been the problem, I noticed that I had an error in my SQL code. Thanks tho!